# Angular 7 Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I'm having this problem to use mat-autocomplete async, I have tried several solutions mainly from here and even then I did not succeed. follow my code ... Thanks

component.ts

```
    filteredEmpresas: Observable<IEmpresaResponse>;
  empresasForm: FormGroup;

this.empresasForm = this.fb.group({
      empresaInput: null
    })

    this.filteredEmpresas = this.empresasForm.get('empresaInput').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        switchMap(value => this.appService.search({text: value}, 1))
      );
```

service.ts

```
    search(filter: {text: string} = {text: ''}, page = 1): 
  Observable<IEmpresaResponse> {

    return this.http.get<IEmpresaResponse>(this.apiURL + '/busca/'+filter.text)
    .pipe(
      tap((response: IEmpresaResponse) => {
        response.results = response.results
          .map(empresa => new Empresa(empresa.idEmpresa, empresa.nomeEmpresa, empresa.ativo));
        return response;
      })
      );
  }
```

class.ts

```
    export class Empresa {
    constructor(public idEmpresa: number, public nomeEmpresa: string, public ativo: Boolean) {}
  }

  export interface IEmpresaResponse {
    total: number;
    results: Empresa[];
  }
```

Comment: in the service, if you change it to .pipe(tap(res => console.log(res)), tap(( etc... what does the console.log show? I guess your response isnt returning an object with a .results field on it

Comment: Did you check the network debug console of your browser? Is the HTTP request actually returning a value with the structure you are expecting? By the way, you wouldn't need to call the constructor, in a tap. If you type the get request with the IEmpresaResponse, the array results would already be of type Empresa because the expected json gets typed already.

Comment: many thanks to all, i have decided to insert any in the ' tap((response: any) '